# Align div in the middle li on ul list

Tags: css, list, html, position, vertical-alignment

I am facing a small problem in time to align my divs inside a `<li>`. I would like to vertically align my div (which has a picture inside), in a way that no matter the height of my `<li>`, it will always be in the middle. NO USE WITH MARGIN-TOP PERCENTAGE (%). Already used the display table but did not work for my case.

Here the picture of how I would like to stay:
[image: a]
[image: b]

How is increased when the height of my `<li>`.
[image: c]

The image is not in the middle of `<li>`. ^

If anyone can help me, this here my file fiddle. Remember without using margin :). In my case I am temporarily using the file fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/T6KrE/37/

```css
#frdImgProfile {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background: #ffe;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-left:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your `<div>`s have fixed height and width of `50px`. Is that intended?

Comment: this css #contactList > li {
   bla..bla..bla..
   120px;
}

Comment: If your `<div class="frdImgProfile">`s have fixed width and height of `50px`, you can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/T6KrE/38/ Note that I changed `id` to `class`, because you are not supposed to have multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: Yes, the id is fixed because I used ctrl c, ctrl v .. what do you mean margin-top:-25px? was it that you changed? Or is there anything else? There is no other way without using margin :) - Thanks for your time ...

Comment: `top:50%;margin-top:-25px`. This is base on the fact that `height:50px` is fixed.

Comment: If I want to increase the size of the div, you have a problem? Or just increase the percentage? thank you

Comment: `-25px` is half of `50px`. If you want to modify the height, modify the negative `margin-top` accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... We'll go for parts:

First: You don't have to abuse with the *id* attributes.

Second: In your CSS code, you have a lot of rules that reference to same id. This is not a good practice. It supposed that the id is unique.

Third:  I've seen that you have a div called: div#avatarUser. I guess that you created this for setting special style. Well you don't need to do this. With parent:first-child or parent:nth-child(1) you can set specific styles for the first element:

E.g.:

```
<ul>
 <li></li> <!-- I want to set specific styles for this element. The first element -->
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
</ul>
```

So, for do that just in my CSS file, I'll put:

```
ul > li:nth-child(1) { /* Your CSS code */ }
```

---

Well, now we deep in your problem.

I changed a little your HTML code, because I think it's more organized and clean code:

```
<div class="frdList">
    <ul class="contactList">
        <li>Friends :)</li>
        <li class="p-flexbox flex-hsc">
            <img src="http://w2.vanillicon.com/2c85954e3b080d9926c53b530ca40317_50.png" />
        </li>
        <li class="p-flexbox flex-hsc">
            <img src="http://w6.vanillicon.com/6cd18e7a56ebd6fb1f3f607823b7d5fe_50.png" />
        </li>
        <li class="p-flexbox flex-hsc">
            <img src="http://wc.vanillicon.com/cd7c7d1f9a0c56ff3b8296527a98564f_50.png" />
        </li>
        <li class="p-flexbox flex-hsc">
            <img src="http://vanillicon.com/0fff488a9952086c6785f260e2c127ad_50.png" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And also changed the CSS file:

```
/* Reset CSS */

body, div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li { list-style: none; }

/* @font-faces imports */

@font-face {
    font-family:'Amatic SC';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Amatic SC Regular'), local('AmaticSC-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/amaticsc/v3/DPPfSFKxRTXvae2bKDzp5D8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}

/* Basic styles */

.frdList {
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
}
.contactList > li:nth-child(1) {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#2da1ec, #0191d9);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#2da1ec, #0191d9);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#2da1ec, #0191d9);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#2da1ec, #0191d9);
    border: 1px solid #0082c3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #077be0;
    position: relative;
    height:55px;
}
.contactList > li:nth-child(1):hover {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#2eacff, #0191d9);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#2eacff, #0191d9);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#2eacff, #0191d9);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#2eacff, #0191d9);
}
.contactList > li:nth-child(1):after {
    content: url("http://images1.wikia.nocookie.net/knd/images/3/3a/PR2.gif");
    text-align: center;
    width: 68px;
    height: 65px;
    background: #8dfd07;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid 1px #aaa;
}
.contactList > li:nth-child(1):before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 78px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: white;
    line-height: 70px;
    /* Well see */
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px #aaa;
    top: -15px;
    left: 10px;
}

.contactList > li {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), inset 0 -2px 2px -2px gray;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ededed, #eff0f2);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#ededed, #eff0f2);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#ededed, #eff0f2);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ededed, #eff0f2);
    border-left: 10px solid green;
    border-right: 1px solid #999999;
    height:120px;
}

.p-flexbox {

   /* Flexbox: Init setup */

   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: box;
}

.flex-hsc {

   /* Flexbox: Principal setup */

   -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
      -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
           box-orient: horizontal;

   -webkit-box-pack: start;
      -moz-box-pack: start;
           box-pack: start;

   -webkit-box-align: center;
      -moz-box-align: center;
           box-align: center;
}
```

To center the images I used Flexible Box Model or Flexbox.

But I think... **Why to complicate? If you know the height of the container of the image, use line-height**

In the development area exists a principle called KIS. It means:

Keep It Simple.

If you have the solution (and a good solution), use it! This will avoid headaches.

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T6KrE/42/).

Try to change the height of the `li` elements in the demo and you will see that the images will always be center.

Cheers,
Leonardo

Comment: Wonder response man! My css were using # id because these styles will only ones! In relation to objects with the same id, are utilized as duplicate (ctrl-c, ctrl-v), as already said up there. My biggest problem was with the same alignment within the div '<li>'. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The code was actually kinda messy, I would organize it at the end of everything. But thanks for the tips!

Comment: Oh, please! It's nothing. I'm glad to help you.

Comment: Man unintentionally abuse ... within (. ContactList> li: nth-child (1): after {....}) there is a picture ... need to insert a css I have to round the edges of this image, I tried to do the following:. ContactList> li: nth-child (1): after img {} ... apparently it did not work. Follows the fiddle updated : http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/T6KrE/45/. Can you tell me how can I do? Thanks again

Comment: No problem @Igao ASP.NET! But I'm not in the computer, I'm from my phone... But I think that you put these rules: contactList > li:nth-child(1):after { border-radius: value; }. If you wait a few, I'll go to my computer and I'd glad to help you.

Comment: Please do not worry! try this way ... so you can help me I will be grateful! thank you very much

Comment: This property already exists in this class ... does not work for the image pair only the div: \. Hug.

Comment: Well, I'm on the computer now.  I've seen the fiddle and let me to say that (in the way we have done) is not possible =/. I changed a little the code again with the purpose of do that and we did it =). Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T6KrE/46/ Cheers, Leo

Comment: Yeah man it was just that :)! Worked perfectly, you removed the direct image of the css is not? But it does not matter :) - Thank you once again!

Comment: Don't worry! I'm glad I helped! Cheers, Leo

Comment: Is it possible to make this cross-browser solution? Try to see this in some other fiddler own browser (eg Firefox, IE), except Opera. He gets a little buggy, it is possible or not? The file that is new here: [HERE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/T6KrE/60/)  Thanked already!

Comment: We should avoid extended discussions in comments. If you want, we can follow this in another place, like via email: lnrd.manrique@gmail.com. Chat would be a good option, but you don't have enough reputation =(.

Comment: Yeah man .. understand! I do not want to take this to a particularity its ... the problem is not yours. :) What I had to say was really just that. If you want to tell me by mail follows: igorverycrazy@gmail.com. - Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

can add .. add you complete classes. ++

```
#contactList > li {
    position:relative;
}
#frdImgProfile {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-25px;
    top:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you won't use margin, try with `line-height` on `li` and `.frdImgProfile`

1. Change `#frdImgProfile` to `.frdImgProfile` and on your html change `id=frdImgProfile` to `class=frdImgProfile`,
2. Remove `margin-top` on `.frdImgProfile`
3. Add `line-height: 120px;` to `#contactList > li`
4. Add `display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;line-height: normal;` to `.frdImgProfile`

---

```
#contactList > li {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), inset 0 -2px 2px -2px gray;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ededed, #eff0f2);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#ededed, #eff0f2);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#ededed, #eff0f2);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ededed, #eff0f2);
    border-left:10px solid green;
    border-right:1px solid #999999;
    height:120px;
    line-height: 120px;
}

.frdImgProfile {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background: #ffe;
    margin-left:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   line-height: normal;
}
```

<kbd>**[demo on cssdeck](http://cssdeck.com/labs/29vos1rc)**</kbd>

Hope this help

Comment: Good answer too. We arrive at the same goal! Thank you for your time! hugs